# All Google Apps Script Triggers Not Running

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Everything was working ok till 5:17 PM GMT+5:30 and all triggers stopped working and I can't debug them because they are not showing in executions tab also

I checked executions tab but not happen I thought that this is server error but not sure and all my work is depended on this